# Android Google Maps - remove marker with icon

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I want to remove a Marker on long click, and place it in another place without clearing the whole map.

Right now the circle radius works fine, but the custom pin icon is not removed. 
using the GoogleMap.clear() method should not be used - there are some other objects on the map I don't want refreshed. 
I have also tried setPosition method and had the very same result.
How to erase this icon?

Marker declaration:

```
marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker.getPosition()).draggable(true).title("INFO")
                    .infoWindowAnchor(0.5f,0.5f).visible(false)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pin_icon))));


this.googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                createMarker(latLng);

            }
        });


private void createMarker(LatLng latLng) {
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true).title("INFO")
                .infoWindowAnchor(0.5f,0.5f)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_pin_gr))));

    }
```

Comment: show code where u add this marker

Answer (score 0):

I used such approach for creating markers and simply `setPosition(new Latlng(...))` working.

```
marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin))
                    .position(new LatLng(cab.getLatitude(), cab.getLongitude())));
```

Did you try to replace `marker.remove();` on `setPosition()` inside `onLongClick()` method ?